# Check if object is a constructor - IsConstructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecma262

I want to check if a JavaScript value is a constructor, that is, if it has a [[Construct]] internal method.

ECMAScript defines [IsConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isconstructor), which does exactly this, but it's an internal operation.

So I want to emulate it. I thought about attempting instantiation or subclassing inside a `try` statement, but neither does work reliably for all cases.

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  try {
    return new value(), true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  try {
    return new value(), true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
var tests = 0,
    failed = 0;  
function test(value, expected, msg) {
  ++tests;
  try {
    var result = isConstructor(window.eval(value));
  } catch(err) {
    result = err;
  }
  if(result !== expected) {
    ++failed;
    console.log('Testing: ' + value + '\nMessage: ' + msg + '\nResult: ' + result + '\nExpected: ' + expected);
  }
}
function testEnd() {
  console.log(failed + ' out of ' + tests + ' tests failed.');
}
test('undefined', false, 'undefined is not a constructor');
test('null', false, 'null is not a constructor');
test('true', false, 'booleans are not constructors');
test('0', false, 'numbers are not constructors');
test('"abc"', false, 'strings are not constructors');
test('Symbol()', false, 'symbols are not constructors');
test('({})', false, '{} is not a constructor');
test('[]', false, 'arrays are not constructors');
test('(function(){})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){throw TypeError()})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){}.bind())', true, 'bounded normal functions are constructors');
test('() => {}', false, 'arrow functions are not constructors');
test('((() => {}).bind())', false, 'bounded arrow functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){})', false, 'generator functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){}.bind())', false, 'bounded generator functions are not constructors');
test('(class{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('(class extends function(){}{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('new Proxy([],{})', false, 'proxies whose target is not constructor are not constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{get:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{construct:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('var r1 = Proxy.revocable([],{}); r1.proxy', false, 'revocable proxies whose target is not a constructor are notconstructors');
test('r1.revoke(); r1.proxy', false, 'revoked proxies whose target was not a constructor are not constructors');
test('var r2 = Proxy.revocable(function(){},{}); r2.proxy', true, 'revocable proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('r2.revoke(); r2.proxy', true, 'revoked proxies whose target was a constructor are constructors');
testEnd();
```

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  if(value === null) return false;
  try {
    return class extends value {}, true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  if(value === null) return false;
  try {
    return class extends value {}, true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
var tests = 0,
    failed = 0;  
function test(value, expected, msg) {
  ++tests;
  try {
    var result = isConstructor(window.eval(value));
  } catch(err) {
    result = err;
  }
  if(result !== expected) {
    ++failed;
    console.log('Testing: ' + value + '\nMessage: ' + msg + '\nResult: ' + result + '\nExpected: ' + expected);
  }
}
function testEnd() {
  console.log(failed + ' out of ' + tests + ' tests failed.');
}
test('undefined', false, 'undefined is not a constructor');
test('null', false, 'null is not a constructor');
test('true', false, 'booleans are not constructors');
test('0', false, 'numbers are not constructors');
test('"abc"', false, 'strings are not constructors');
test('Symbol()', false, 'symbols are not constructors');
test('({})', false, '{} is not a constructor');
test('[]', false, 'arrays are not constructors');
test('(function(){})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){throw TypeError()})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){}.bind())', true, 'bounded normal functions are constructors');
test('() => {}', false, 'arrow functions are not constructors');
test('((() => {}).bind())', false, 'bounded arrow functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){})', false, 'generator functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){}.bind())', false, 'bounded generator functions are not constructors');
test('(class{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('(class extends function(){}{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('new Proxy([],{})', false, 'proxies whose target is not constructor are not constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{get:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{construct:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('var r1 = Proxy.revocable([],{}); r1.proxy', false, 'revocable proxies whose target is not a constructor are notconstructors');
test('r1.revoke(); r1.proxy', false, 'revoked proxies whose target was not a constructor are not constructors');
test('var r2 = Proxy.revocable(function(){},{}); r2.proxy', true, 'revocable proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('r2.revoke(); r2.proxy', true, 'revoked proxies whose target was a constructor are constructors');
testEnd();
```

Is there some way to test it reliably? If not in ES6 or ES7, maybe in some draft or proposed feature?

Comment: You could potentially just check if there is a prototype? Or something like `try { (new constructor()) instanceof constructor }`?

Comment: @somethinghere The problem is that constructors may throw, so it's not a reliable test.

Comment: There is nothing, but it pops up in esdicuss regularly: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/determine-if-a-value-is-callable-constructible

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the link, I wasn't subscribed to esdicuss back then.

Comment: Would you mind closing as a duplicate of (and merging your answer into) [How to check if a Javascript function is a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922531/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-function-is-a-constructor)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based on the code posted by [Jason Orendorff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94977/jason-orendorff) on [esdicuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/add-reflect-isconstructor-and-reflect-iscallable#content-2).

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  try {
    new new Proxy(value, {construct() { return {}; }});
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
function isConstructor(value) {
  try {
    new new Proxy(value, {construct() { return {}; }});
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
var tests = 0,
    failed = 0;
function test(value, expected, msg) {
  ++tests;
  try {
    var result = isConstructor(window.eval(value));
  } catch(err) {
    result = err;
  }
  if(result !== expected) {
    ++failed;
    console.log('Testing: ' + value + '\nMessage: ' + msg + '\nResult: ' + result + '\nExpected: ' + expected);
  }
}
function testEnd() {
  console.log(failed + ' out of ' + tests + ' tests failed.');
}
test('undefined', false, 'undefined is not a constructor');
test('null', false, 'null is not a constructor');
test('true', false, 'booleans are not constructors');
test('0', false, 'numbers are not constructors');
test('"abc"', false, 'strings are not constructors');
test('Symbol()', false, 'symbols are not constructors');
test('({})', false, '{} is not a constructor');
test('[]', false, 'arrays are not constructors');
test('(function(){})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){throw TypeError()})', true, 'normal functions are constructors');
test('(function(){}.bind())', true, 'bounded normal functions are constructors');
test('() => {}', false, 'arrow functions are not constructors');
test('((() => {}).bind())', false, 'bounded arrow functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){})', false, 'generator functions are not constructors');
test('(function*(){}.bind())', false, 'bounded generator functions are not constructors');
test('(class{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('(class extends function(){}{})', true, 'classes are constructors');
test('new Proxy([],{})', false, 'proxies whose target is not constructor are not constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{get:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('new Proxy(function(){},{construct:()=>{throw TypeError()}})', true, 'proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('var r1 = Proxy.revocable([],{}); r1.proxy', false, 'revocable proxies whose target is not a constructor are notconstructors');
test('r1.revoke(); r1.proxy', false, 'revoked proxies whose target was not a constructor are not constructors');
test('var r2 = Proxy.revocable(function(){},{}); r2.proxy', true, 'revocable proxies whose target is a constructor are constructors');
test('r2.revoke(); r2.proxy', true, 'revoked proxies whose target was a constructor are constructors');
testEnd();
```

Proxy objects are only constructors if their initial target was a constructor. From [ProxyCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxycreate),

> If *target* has a [[Construct]] internal method, then
>
> - Set the [[Construct]] internal method of *P* as specified in [9.5.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-construct-argumentslist-newtarget).

Therefore, the code creates a proxy object whose target is the value we want to check, and whose handler has a construct trap which doesn't throw.

This way, if the proxy is a constructor (i.e. the tested value is a constructor), when instantiated it will run the code in the trap instead of redirecting the operation to the target, and it won't throw. If the proxy is not a constructor (i.e. the tested value is neither), when instantiated it will throw an error.

There is a little problem, though. When creating a proxy, the target must be either a non-proxy object, or a non-revoked proxy object. Otherwise, it throws, and thus the code above considers it a non-constructor.

This is OK in case of primitives, because they can't be constructors. However, revoked proxies can be constructors or not, and we can't test them properly.

You might want to [detect if the value is a revoked proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39335909/1529630) in order to handle that case differently.