# Check if proxy object is revoked

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

ECMAScript 6 introduces proxy object, which may be created as revocable.

How can I detect if a proxy has been revoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Proxy` constructor only accepts targets and handlers when they are objects and are not revoked proxies. From [ProxyCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxycreate),

> 1. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*target*) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 2. If *target* is a Proxy exotic object and the value of the [[ProxyHandler]] [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) of *target* is null, throw a TypeError exception.

This allows you to check if a value is a revoked proxy: you only need to [ensure that it's an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187058/1529630) but makes `Proxy` throw.

Something like this should work:

```
function isRevokedProxy(value) {
  try {
    new Proxy(value, value);
    return false;
  } catch(err) {
    return Object(value) === value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really slick, because a revoked proxy has no accessibility, but `typeof (RevokedProxy)` does not trigger a TypeError like any other operation — great solution.